# Cannot start odoo server importerror web_kanban not found

Tags: odoo-8

After creating odoo modules I am trying to start Odoo v8 server but When I  run the server using this command i got an error

```
./openerp-server --addons=openerp/addons,/home/user/Desktop/odoo_test  --xmlrpc-port 8888 -d demo_db -u demo
```

I'm getting errors something like:

```
2017-02-10 14:00:32,046 29614 INFO ? openerp: OpenERP version 8.0
2017-02-10 14:00:32,046 29614 INFO ? openerp: addons paths: ['/home/software/.local/share/Odoo/addons/8.0', u'/home/software/odoo_8/openerp/addons', u'/home/software/Desktop/odoo_test']
2017-02-10 14:00:32,046 29614 INFO ? openerp: database hostname: localhost
2017-02-10 14:00:32,046 29614 INFO ? openerp: database port: 5432
2017-02-10 14:00:32,046 29614 INFO ? openerp: database user: software
2017-02-10 14:00:32,047 29614 WARNING ? openerp.modules.module: module web: module not found
2017-02-10 14:00:32,047 29614 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: Couldn't load module web
2017-02-10 14:00:32,047 29614 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: No module named web
2017-02-10 14:00:32,047 29614 ERROR ? openerp.service.server: Failed to load server-wide module `web`.
The `web` module is provided by the addons found in the `openerp-web` project.
Maybe you forgot to add those addons in your addons_path configuration.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/software/odoo_8/openerp/service/server.py", line 878, in load_server_wide_modules
    openerp.modules.module.load_openerp_module(m)
  File "/home/software/odoo_8/openerp/modules/module.py", line 315, in load_openerp_module
    __import__('openerp.addons.' + module_name)
  File "/home/software/odoo_8/openerp/modules/module.py", line 79, in load_module
    f, path, descr = imp.find_module(module_part, ad_paths)
ImportError: No module named web
2017-02-10 14:00:32,068 29614 WARNING ? openerp.modules.module: module web_kanban: module not found
2017-02-10 14:00:32,068 29614 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: Couldn't load module web_kanban
2017-02-10 14:00:32,069 29614 CRITICAL ? openerp.modules.module: No module named web_kanban
2017-02-10 14:00:32,069 29614 ERROR ? openerp.service.server: Failed to load server-wide module `web_kanban`.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/software/odoo_8/openerp/service/server.py", line 878, in load_server_wide_modules
    openerp.modules.module.load_openerp_module(m)
  File "/home/software/odoo_8/openerp/modules/module.py", line 315, in load_openerp_module
    __import__('openerp.addons.' + module_name)
  File "/home/software/odoo_8/openerp/modules/module.py", line 79, in load_module
    f, path, descr = imp.find_module(module_part, ad_paths)
ImportError: No module named web_kanban
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error only occurs due to wrong path please check your addons path and path where you run this command or you can also try with -

./openerp-server --addons=addons